# Laravel 5.1 with wamp fail to create new project with vendor

Tags: php, windows, laravel, composer-php, wamp

Code error message:

```
c:\wamp64\www\test>composer update
> php artisan clear-compiled
```

> Warning:
>   require(C:\wamp64\www\test\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\wamp64\www\test\bootstra p\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\wamp64\www\test\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\
>       test\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output:

update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scrip
ts] [--no-progress] [--with-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--p
refer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Steps I followed so far:
1) Re-install the composer,
2) update the composer,
3) type composer update --no-scripts. In that case it works and downloads the vendor but then there is a problem when I run php artisan serve.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in
>   C:\wamp64\www\test\server.php on line 17

4) So I guess the problem is somewhere in artisan.php or server.php or the PATH is wrong. I dont know why the separator is changed. (\bootstrap/../)

I have to say also the composer and artisan works perfectly when suddenly in my other project (not test) shows me white screen.

Comment: Try first remove full vendor folder then run "composer install".May be it will work

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\wamp\www\test\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with an error

php artisan error

Comment: first remove all lines from bootstrap/cache/services.json then remove vendor folder then run "composer install"

Comment: the only file in bootstrap>cache is gitignore

Comment: I tryed to download the version of Laravel 5.1.0 and is working.

I cant figure out why is not working on 5.1.11 & 5.1.4